# AR Parrot drone 2.0 as a webcam

Tags: webcam, ar.drone

I am using the AR Parrot drone 2.0, and I want to somehow "trick" the PC into thinking that the video stream coming from it is a second webcam.

The reason is that I want to use some existing computer vision libraries, and it would much more straight forward to just specify which webcam is the source of the video stream, on which the algorithms will run.

I came across an [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drone-cam-for-your-ar.drone/id586373241?mt=8) that streams video from the AR drone, but it seems to stream it on iPhones/iPads and not on computer devices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a full app or do you want to create one by yourself?

I'm working with an AR.Drone 2.0 for a research project and although it is an old device which makes it complicated to find resources, there are... and lots of them.

If you want to create your own app, you don't say which language / platform you want to use it. If you want to use Java, you can use YADrone. It has a good API and it also has examples, including a full application that can be used.

https://vsis-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/oldServer/teaching//projects/yadrone/